# Insert nil image into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS does not seem to allow insertion of a nil image into a NSDictionary. Can i feed it a nil image?

I have my NSDictionary setup as follows:

```
NSDictionary *record = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.mainImage.image, 1.0), @"tagData", 
   self.firstname, @"firstname", 
   self.lastname, @"lastname", nil];
```

The data i want to insert

```
NSDictionary1 contains NSString(Fabian), NSString(Toulouse), NSData(JPGFILE)
NSDictionary2 contains NSString(Kindle), NSString(May)     , NSData()
NSDictionary3 contains NSString(Far)   , NSString(Ney)     , NSData(JPGFIle)
NSDictionary4 contains NSString(Here)  , NSString(There)   , NSData()
NSDictionary5 contains NSString(Sam)   , NSString(Sung)    , NSData()
NSDictionary6 contains NSString(IBM)   , NSString(HP)      , NSData(JPGFIle)
```

Tableview displays with the dataset above.

```
S/no    First Name    Last Name       Image
 1        Fabian       Toulouse       JPGFILE   
 2        Kindle       May            PNGFILE
 3        Far          Ney            JPGFIle
 2
 2
 6        IBM          HP             JPGFIle
```

I tried the following

```
NSDictionary *record = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   Nil, @"tagData", 
   self.firstname, @"firstname", 
   self.lastname, @"lastname", nil];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *record = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   Null, @"tagData", 
   self.firstname, @"firstname", 
   self.lastname, @"lastname", nil];
```

but they don't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `[NSNull null]` to represent a nill value inside a collection. nill/null will raise an exception

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! It did fix my problem. But I've tried with nil or NULL, both are accepted by the Xcode parser. But the code worked only with [NSNull null]